# Convert jsonarray to string

Tags: java, mysql, string, arrays

I want to put value of first query (course) to other query (mapcategory) in my code.
The value in first query not convert to string in second query.

```
public String query() throws Exception {
        JSONObject inputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray inputArray = new JSONArray();
        String array=null;
        Database db = new Database();
        db.my_Connection();
        List<HashMap> course =  db.Query("select NAME from file where visual_code='1'");
        inputArray = new JSONArray();
        if(course !=null)
            for (int i=0; i<course.size(); i++){
                HashMap data=(HashMap)course.get(i);
                inputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
                inputJsonObj.put("NAME",(String) data.get("NAME"));     
                inputArray.put(inputJsonObj);
            }
        arra=String.valueOf(course);
        List<HashMap> mapCategory =  db.Query("select PATH from c_"+arra+"_item item" +
                " LEFT JOIN cr_"+arra+"_document doc" +
                " ON item.ref = doc.id WHERE visibility = 1 AND tool = 'document'");
        inputArray = new JSONArray();
        if(mapCategory !=null)
            for (int i=0; i<mapCategory.size(); i++){
                HashMap data=(HashMap)mapCategory.get(i);
                inputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
                inputJsonObj.put("PATH",(String) data.get("PATH"));
                inputArray.put(inputJsonObj);
            }
        db.Close_Connection();
        return inputArray.toString();
    }
```

i debuging this code and get an eror

> HTTP Status 500 -
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.MappableContainerException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '{NAME=TUTORIAL}_item_property item LEFT JOIN
>   crs_{NAME=TUTORIAL}_d' at line 1

I want get value only "TUTORIAL" in result.

Comment: error it self explains that you have error in your query, first try to run query in you dbms and try in your code, it is one of the best practice to avoid error or exceptions like `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`

Comment: my query and the result is true. i want get value from the result of my query, but always show [{NAME=TUTORIAL}]. i want get value "TUTORIAL" only in my result. So, what i must to do??

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in `arra=String.valueOf(course);` cuz you are save string representation of hashmap in string instead you need a value from hashmap.

replace

```
arra=String.valueOf(course);
```

to

```
arra=course.get("NAME");
```

Comment: i got an eror the method get(int) in type List<HashMap> is not applicable for the arguments(String).